# High-performance, variable-length fading edges on a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-animation, core-graphics

I'm trying to produce some fading edges on a `UIScrollView` with a fairly complex hierarchy, with lengths that can be easily adjusted on scroll. This is basically the effect I'm trying to achieve (notice the fading edges):

[image]

The tricky parts are:

1. The fact the background is dynamic
2. I want the fading edges to "grow" as the user scrolls; that is, they aren't there when scrolling is not occurring, but once scrolling begins, the fade effect increases as the `contentOffset` increases
3. Similar to no. 2, the fading edges should shrink down smoothly once scrolling is complete

I've gotten most of what I want using a custom `CAGradientLayer` that is used as the `mask` of the view's layer, but the problem is that it's not adequate performance-wise. I then tried toggling the mask on-demand, ie. when scrolling begins, the mask is set, and when scrolling stops, the mask is removed. This sort of worked (there were some bugs), but I later discovered that changing the mask on the fly had undefined behaviour, according to the Apple documentation. I haven't determined a CoreGraphics-based solution yet, and I'm not sure if it will be feasible or if the performance will be any better. I also can't use an image to simulate the gradient, because both the content and the background are dynamic.

This is the implementation of the custom `CAGradientLayer` subclass I've created:

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;

        self.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
        self.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);

        CGColorRef transluscentColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0].CGColor;
        CGColorRef opaqueColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

        self.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       (id)opaqueColor,
                       (id)transluscentColor, 
                       (id)opaqueColor, 
                       (id)opaqueColor,
                       (id)transluscentColor,
                       (id)opaqueColor, nil];
        self.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f], nil];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) setAbsoluteStartPoint:(CGPoint)startPoint endPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint {
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    self.startPoint = CGPointMake(startPoint.x / self.bounds.size.width, startPoint.y / self.bounds.size.height);
    self.endPoint = CGPointMake(endPoint.x / self.bounds.size.width, endPoint.y / self.bounds.size.height);
    [CATransaction commit];
}

- (void) setGradientStartLength:(CGFloat)startLength endLength:(CGFloat)endLength animated:(BOOL)animated {
    CGFloat deltaX = (self.endPoint.x - self.startPoint.x);
    CGFloat deltaY = (self.endPoint.y - self.startPoint.y);

    // use the side whose change is largest as our base length
    CGFloat sideLength = (deltaX > deltaY ? self.bounds.size.width * deltaX : self.bounds.size.height * deltaY);

    CGFloat startRatio = MAX((startLength / sideLength), 0.0f);
    CGFloat endRatio = 1.0f - MAX((endLength / sideLength), 0.0f);

    NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:startRatio],
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:endRatio],
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f], nil];

    [CATransaction begin];
    if (animated) {
        [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
    }
    else {
        [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    }

    self.locations = locations;
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

When used with my `UIScrollView`, I basically just adjust the layer's `position` to match the `contentOffset`, and then adjust the size using `setGradientStartLength:endLength:animated:` without animation (animation doesn't slow things down much though).

Like I said, this will do what I want, but not at the level of performance I need (the framerate dips from 60fps to around 30 with it used as the scroll view's `mask`). And I haven't figured out a good way to do this without using the `mask` property, which I assume is the way I'll have to do it.

My guess is that this is achievable using similar code as above, but using my layer as a sublayer instead of the view's `mask`. But I haven't determined how to add the fade effect like this when the layer is used as a sublayer, and I haven't seen any examples of anyone else having done the same.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I find Apple's documentation on these things is very limited.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the effect you're trying to achieve? May prompt some suggestions.

Comment: Sure. I added an image and a better description of the effect.